# Magento2: How to show shipping method condition wise?

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, shopping-cart-price-rules, product-weight

I want to show shipping method base on total product weight.

I have 2 Shipping method A and B.

If total shipping weight equal or less than 150. Then will show shipping method A

If total shipping weight greater than 150. Then will show shipping method B.

Anyone can explain how to apply shipping method condition total product weight wise?

Comment: What about using max package weight??

Comment: Yes, apply the condition on total shipping weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In collectRates function of specific shipping method, add logic to check weight of cart item.

For example, in collectRates method of shipping method A, add following logic.
// Add logic to calculate cartweight
if ($cartweight > 150 ) {
return false;
}

Comment: Thanks for the answer to my question. If you any method through cart price rules by admin panel. please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

thankyou for your suggestion. this is a very good suggestion.

add condition in app/code/Ests/EchoShipping/Model/Carrier echoshipping.php

add a condition in collectRates method

$weight = $request->getPackageWeight();
if ($weight < 50 ) { return false; }

I got success.